# Operators in javascript for table.where objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Not sure if I titled that correctly if not lets correct it. The problem I’m having is when filtering data from a table I want to be able to compare an int and determine if it’s less than another int. So far I’ve searched all i can on google and have found not been able to find anything that will work.

Here is my code.

```
var mytable = tables.getTable('Table');
mytable.where({ numbertocompare : 10 }).read(
{
```

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
var mytable = tables.getTable('Table');
mytable.where({ numbertocompare < 10 }).read(
{
```

Notice the < symbol instead

This is being done in javascript backend for azure mobile services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a function rather than an object.

```
mytable.where(function () {
    //this points to the row
    //use this.columnName to access column values
    return this.numbertocompare < 10;
})
```

See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj613353).

Comment: I tried something similar to this using the page you gave me and for some reason didnt work but now it does. This is correct tho.